# How to clear input fields in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

So after pressing `<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Create</button>` i create a card with hero. Then  `.then(() => clearFields())` helps me to clear input fields because сlicking the Сreate button again returns a blank card. That is, I see that the card was cleared of information correctly. But visually, the fields remain filled in.

How do I make the input fields clear after pressing `<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Create</button>`?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { heroCreate } from '../../actions';
import { useHttp } from '../../hooks/http.hook';

const HeroesAddForm = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [element, setElement] = useState('');
    const {request} = useHttp();

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const clearFields = () => {
        setName('');
        setDescription('');
        setElement('');
    }
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const newHero = {
            id: uuidv4(),
            name: name,
            description: description,
            element: element
        }
        request("http://localhost:3001/heroes", "POST", JSON.stringify(newHero))
        .then(dispatch(heroCreate(newHero)))
        .then(() => clearFields())
        .catch(err => console.log(err));   
        
    }
    return (
        <form className="border p-4 shadow-lg rounded" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label fs-4">Name of new hero</label>
                <input
                    required
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    className="form-control"
                    // id="name" 
                    onChange={event => setName(event.target.value)}
                    placeholder="What is your name?" />
            </div>

            <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="text" className="form-label fs-4">Description</label>
                <textarea
                    required
                    name="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    // id="text" 
                    placeholder="Tell us something about your hero"
                    onChange={event => setDescription(event.target.value)}
                    style={{ "height": '130px' }} />
            </div>

            <div className="mb-3">
                <label htmlFor="element" className="form-label">Choose hero element</label>
                <select
                    required
                    className="form-select"
                    id="element"
                    onChange={event => setElement(event.target.value)}
                    name="element">
                    <option >I have the element of...</option>
                    <option value="fire">Fire</option>
                    <option value="water">Water</option>
                    <option value="wind">Wind</option>
                    <option value="earth">Earth</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </form>
    )
}

export default HeroesAddForm;
```

I wrote the code this way because I thought that `.then(() => clearFields())` would clear the fields after the query is executed and the action creator is dispatched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Sure, the `clearFields` handler resets the local `name`, `description`, and `element` state values, but since your form fields are not ***fully controlled*** they don't actually update until you manually edit the inputs.

There is also a minor issue in the PUT request response processing calling the `dispatch` immediately instead of after the `request` resolves.

## Solution

You have 2 trivial options:

### Fully Controlled Inputs

Fully controlled inputs use React state and pass both a `value` ***and*** `onChange` handler to the inputs. In other words, the value is controlled by the state.

```
const HeroesAddForm = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [element, setElement] = useState("");
  const { request } = useHttp();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const clearFields = () => {
    setName("");
    setDescription("");
    setElement("");
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const newHero = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name,
      description,
      element
    };

    request("http://localhost:3001/heroes", "POST", JSON.stringify(newHero))
      .then(() => dispatch(heroCreate(newHero))) // <-- arrow function call dispatch
      .then(clearFields)
      .catch(console.log);
  };

  return (
    <form className="border p-4 shadow-lg rounded" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label fs-4">
          Name of new hero
        </label>
        <input
          required
          type="text"
          name="name"
          className="form-control"
          onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
          value={name} // <-- provide value
          placeholder="What is your name?"
        />
      </div>

      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="text" className="form-label fs-4">
          Description
        </label>
        <textarea
          required
          name="description"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Tell us something about your hero"
          onChange={(event) => setDescription(event.target.value)}
          value={description} // <-- provide value
          style={{ height: "130px" }}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="element" className="form-label">
          Choose hero element
        </label>
        <select
          required
          className="form-select"
          id="element"
          onChange={(event) => setElement(event.target.value)}
          value={element} // <-- provide value
          name="element"
        >
          <option disabled value="">
            I have the element of...
          </option>
          <option value="fire">Fire</option>
          <option value="water">Water</option>
          <option value="wind">Wind</option>
          <option value="earth">Earth</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
        Create
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

### Fully Un-controlled Inputs

Fully uncontrolled inputs do not use React state and pass neither `value` or `onChange` handlers to the inputs. Use the `form` element's `onSubmit` handler to access the form field values and reset the form.

```
const HeroesAddForm = () => {
  const { request } = useHttp();

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { description, element, name } = event.target;

    const newHero = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: name.value,
      description: description.value,
      element: element.value
    };

    request("http://localhost:3001/heroes", "POST", JSON.stringify(newHero))
      .then(() => dispatch(heroCreate(newHero)))
      .then(() => event.target.reset())
      .catch(console.log);
  };

  return (
    <form className="border p-4 shadow-lg rounded" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label fs-4">
          Name of new hero
        </label>
        <input
          required
          type="text"
          name="name"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="What is your name?"
        />
      </div>

      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="text" className="form-label fs-4">
          Description
        </label>
        <textarea
          required
          name="description"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Tell us something about your hero"
          style={{ height: "130px" }}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="element" className="form-label">
          Choose hero element
        </label>
        <select
          required
          className="form-select"
          id="element"
          defaultValue="" // <-- default value
          name="element"
        >
          <option disabled value="">
            I have the element of...
          </option>
          <option value="fire">Fire</option>
          <option value="water">Water</option>
          <option value="wind">Wind</option>
          <option value="earth">Earth</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
        Create
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // Perform your post request here, e.g., using fetch or axios

  try {
    // Assuming a successful post request
    await postData(formData);

    // Clear form fields after successful post
    setFormData({
      fieldName1: '',
      fieldName2: '',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error submitting form:', error);
  }
};
```